# New Outlook 365 (v-1.2024.111.100): Outlook manilla envelope doesn't show in Taskbar to indicate new mail arrival

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, taskbar

Does anyone know how to get the manilla envelope to appear in the taskbar when you get a new email in Outlook? The screenshot with a blue background theme shows the manilla envelope icon I am asking about.

[image]

Old outlook had a checkbox option for this. The 'new' outlook doesn't have an option for this.

---

Informational: Tips on configuring 'new' Outlook for those interested…

Below are instructions for how to stop the 'new email pop-up' from showing up:

[image: Outlook settings menu open]

[image: go to mail notification settings]

[image: prevent new email pop-up]

[image: stop thread view for emails in outlook]

---

Here is the version of Outlook this question is about. It seems better to state the version instead of just saying 'new' like MS seems to enjoy labeling their products lately.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my search, this feature is temporarily not supported in the new Outlook. In addition, some users have reported this problem in the dedicated feedback portal. You can follow this link to get updates:https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/a595b540-a88f-ee11-a81c-0022484f9f6d

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the only option if you want that functionality may be to switch back to normal/classic Outlook.

MS might well list it as "New Outlook", but when you look at the user interface and the available functionality it's far more like what you'd find with the old Windows 10 built in Mail app. There's a lot of well established functionality in Outlook that isn't available in "New Outlook", including for instance some types of mailboxes not being supported.

Even the app icon is the shape of the Mail icon, reskinned to look similar to Outlook, and the general look and feel of the app is very much like Mail. So if the Mail app didn't put the new message envelope in the task tray (which I don't think it did), I wouldn't be at all surprised that New Outlook doesn't either.